# Docker container running Spring Boot application not answering requests

Tags: spring, docker

I am running a Docker container on my system with a Spring Boot application, but I am getting "empty reply from server" messages when trying to curl to `localhost:8080`, `0.0.0.0:8080` or `myipaddress:8080`. I am new to Docker and I don't know why the server isn't responding. `docker ps` shows the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
5ff52ba449fd   springio/test          "java -jar /app.jar"   2 hours ago     Up 2 hours     0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   eloquent_hertz
```

Docker command to run:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 springio/test
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Dockerfile` seems to be correct. I quickly tested it out with a simple springboot application, and it worked fine. I would assume this problem comes from the application itself. Have you defined a mapping inside your application for the endpoint your curling to? so `@GetMapping("/")` or something similar?

Comment: I figured it out, something was wrong with my port configuration inside my spring boot application so you are right. Anyway, thanks for helping me and making the effort. Really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. If you could accept my answer as accepted, if you deem it worthy, that would be awesome!

Comment: Thought I couldn't do it because I am a newbie, seems I can :)

Answer (score -1):

What does your browser say when you open localhost:8080?

Comment: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE is the response from chrome, safari states it can't open a connection

Comment: @philgsk I get the same error.